# Windows 10 Home: Windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I'm on a 64bit machine running Windows 10 Home.IIS Version 10

I'm trying to use windows authentication on IIS Server. I only see 4 options on IIS server: Anonymous Authentication, ASP.NET Impersonation, Basic Authentication and Forms Authentication. 
I tried searching online and found out that I needed to enable it under windows features > IIS > Security. But I don't have that checkbox. Please see the below images. 
[image: IIS Manager]
[image: Windows Feature]
So my question is: Does windows 10 home support windows authentication and if yes then how to enable it? Anyone using Windows 10 home please comment

Comment: No, it doesn't. Buy and upgrade to Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 32):

Windows 10 Home edition doesn't include Windows Authentication (and a bunch of other IIS security features). However, the package with these features is sitting right there in your OS and you can manually install it.

All you need to do is open an elevated command prompt and run:

> dism /online /norestart /add-package:%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.16299.15.mum

- *Filename above may be slightly different since it's based on your system's bitness and version*

Then just make your way back to:

> Turn Windows features on or off > Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Security

All the "pro" options under Security will be available. Simply check "Windows Authentication" and reboot.

Comment: At first I copied the name of the wrong package and then I saw my mistake and the magic happened. Thank you so much

Comment: I tried this and got some errors: An error occurred trying to open - C:\WINDOWS\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.16299.15.mum Error: 0x80070002
An error occurred trying to open - C:\WINDOWS\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.16299.15.mum Error: 0x80070002

Error: 2

An error occurred trying to open - C:\WINDOWS\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.16299.15.mum Error: 0x80070002

Comment: @ekolis, you must have upaded your windows, try searching for version number at the end.

Comment: @ekolis, you have to go to c:\Windows\servicing\Packages\ and find a similar package. For example, for Windows 1903 build 10.0.18362 this command works for me: dism /online /norestart /add-package:%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.18362.1.mum

Comment: For Windows 11 (build 22621) :
dism /online /norestart /add-package:Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.22621.608.mum

Answer (score 5):

Elaborating a little to answer from coldfused.
Since I encountered errors (reason as stated by coldfused), followed these steps -
Errors something like - *An error occurred trying to open - C:\Windows\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.16299.15.mum Error: 0x80070003*

(i) Goto File explorer - type %SystemRoot% on the bar
(ii) Goto Servicing>Packages>
(iii) Enter IIS in Search to get list of available package
(iv) Now, filter most appropriate for your system. You can check package mentioned by coldfused with available on your system.

*AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.16299.15.mum (mentioned by **coldfused**)
AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.15063.0.mum (on my system)*

so I created the whole command as under -
dism /online /norestart /add-package:%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.15063.0.mum

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Just for the record, I had to do it with the following package: `Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-ServerCommon-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.18362.418.mum`